# Edit Suggestion rejected: What could have been done better, differently?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I'm asking for guidance on how to avoid having my edits rejected in the future. I stumbled upon an helpful but slightly outdated answer, which I decided to update.

Here's [the rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15199197), on an answer about nginx.

The reason for rejecting was:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits
>   that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of
>   the post's owner.

Though, the original answer was composed of only two things :

- `What you're looking for is proxy_intercept_errors`
- A copy/paste of nginx documentation directive

I updated outdated (redirected) links then 
I updated the configuration directive copy/paste fixing an error.

What's wrong!? I really think it preserves pretty nicely OP goal to expose nginx `proxy_intercept_errors` directive...

Comment: Why didn't you commented first and see if the OP will update their answer? They were last seen on Feb 10, so they are active SO user. And anyway - A comment would be also helpful in any case

Comment: @AlonEitan Not enough rep?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yeah, good point. Nevertheless, I still think that: A. It's more like a rewrite than a simple edit, and B - The comments reputation restriction is too high and unnecessary (But this is off-topic to this post)

Comment: @AlonEitan: It's a 'rewrite' content-length-wise, true; but an edit of obsolete content nonetheless, from 2012... I could have mentioned OP, or just do the work right away like i did, in my mind letting a cleaner state to future readers (less "blabla").

Comment: @ppython I do believe that your edit was only for good intention, but If you need to rewrite someone else's answer, then you should notify them using a comment of maybe just post a new answer. I forgot about the comments limitation for users so I have upvoted one of your answers to make sure you have enough to comment on SO. I don't like this comment reputation limitations - I don't see and good in it

Comment: Thanks, @AlonEitan, I could indeed not add comment on other users posts.  Finally, I think I got what this community wants in term of "not rewriting" even though I still think it's counterproductive :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You more or less just re-wrote the entire answer.

If you have your own answer that you would like to provide to a question, post your own answer, don't edit someone else's answer to replace their answer with yours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did rewrite the "entire" copy/paste, wich was obsolete (2012)and not to be easily found on the internets anymore.  Though the original intent and context of OP was respected; didn't it?!

Comment: @ppython Your answer was similar to theirs.  It was still a separate answer though, given how much you decided to change.

Comment: Ok, so from what I get, it's better leaving obsolete content for the next one, and add extra actual information buried down the page. thanks